# C# program exits when I run .RemoveAt() for Lists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand C#. Every thing was going fine until I tried to remove an item from a List.

when the program gets to the code where mylist.RemoveAt(0) is, it just quits. it doesn't even show an error, it just quits with code (0).

What I want to happen is for the string to get deleted and nothing show up between "next enter....." and "there should be....."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace understanding_c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

            mylist.Add("this is my first addition to the list");
            for(int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mylist[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("next enter will delete the first entry");
            Console.Read();
            mylist.RemoveAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mylist[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("there should not have been any entry between this and the last time");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This seems to work fine for me](https://repl.it/@piboistudios/BrilliantDesertedParameters). Are you getting any sort of exit code or error message?

Comment: Surround your code with a try/catch and write out any exception - what happens now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ReadLine() not Read().  The problem is at the first Read it still waits for Enter to continue.  Then it just rolls past the second Read() statement.  The logic is fine, you just don't see the result in the Console

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

mylist.Add("this is my first addition to the list");
for(int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mylist[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("next enter will delete the first entry");
Console.ReadLine();
mylist.RemoveAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mylist[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("there should not have been any entry between this and the last time");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? How can you be sure what the problem even is if the OP has not posted it yet?

Comment: The problem is the program just exits when you type a character into the Console.  The OP's code runs just fine, it's just he never sees the result because the console window closes right away.  Using ReadLine it waits for the return to run and then waits for additional input before closing

Comment: The OP says it quits with code 0.  It runs, he is simply not seeing the result because it processes past the Read() statement without stopping

Comment: fair point actually... This -just- may be the answer, sorry for hard balling you. If you edit your answer I'd be glad to change my downvote to an upvote (SO won't let me change it otherwise)

Comment: wow, it was that simple. guess I need to research the differences between Read() and  ReadLine(). thanks for the answer

Comment: This is the correct answer, even if the reasons presented are not clear.  For clarification, by using Console.Read(), the program is capturing a carriage return (\r\n) from the user, which is technically two separate ASCII codes.  The first Console.Read() captures \r, while the second Console.Read() captures \n, causing the program to immediately exit.  This can be verified by storing the Console.Read() in a variable, and then using Console.WriteLine() to see the result.  The first generates ASCII code 13 (carriage return) and the second generates ASCII code 10 (new line).